# Create Custom URL Scheme Actions

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, url, url-scheme

I know how to create custom `URL schemes` but how can I add actions to them? How would I pass info into my app.

Any suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to figure out the actions.. But here's an example:

```
yourAppURL://doSomething
```

or

```
yourAppURL://doAnotherThing
```

and then in your `AppDelegate`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application handleOpenURL:(NSURL *)url {
    NSString *text = [[url host] stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"doSomething"]) {
        // then do something
    }
    if ([text isEqualToString:@"doAnotherThing"]) {
        // do another thing
    }
}
```

You could potentially do all kinds of stuff by sending various text in the URL. For example, Facebook uses it to open up the app to go directly to a profile with `facebook://profile=username`